# Cassandra DB secondary index

Tags: cassandra

I am starting to look at the Cassandra DB, something draw my attention in terms of its consistency aspect.
I notice in order to do the secondary index, it needs to create another column family to store the keys and values reversely, so then the values I would try to search for become the keys  in index purposed column family.

Then the question comes. For example, a column family encapsulating the user name and the user's living city. Its index column family has the city as the key and the underlying value is a list of the row keys of the original "user-city" column family.

What if I change a user's city in the "user-city" column family, will Cassandra automatically update the corresponding index, such as remove/add the row key of the affected records from the corresponding index column family?

Comment: yes, it will happen automagically..

Comment: @sdolgy you should make this an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will happen automatically, as a nice convenience to you ...